# Two terms that I want to understand: weakest topology and jointly continuous (in the following context).

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I was reading an article online, please help me to understand the following lines (in bold letters). - 
Topological structure:
If (V, ‖·‖) is a normed vector space, the norm ‖·‖ induces a metric and therefore a topology on V.the distance between two vectors u and v is given by ‖u−v‖.

**This topology is precisely the *weakest topology* which makes ‖·‖ continuous** and which is compatible with the linear structure of V in the following sense:

**1.The vector addition + : V × V → V is jointly continuous with respect to this topology. This follows directly from the triangle inequality.**

**2.The scalar multiplication · : K × V → V, where K is the underlying scalar field of V, is jointly continuous. This follows from the triangle inequality and homogeneity of the norm.**

---

Please explain me the Weak topology and how does it makes norm ‖·‖ continuous. what does it mean by "Addition + : V × V → V is jointly continuous with respect to this topology"

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The norm $\|\cdot\|$ is a function from $V$ to $\Bbb R$. There are many topologies that can be placed on $V$ that make this function continuous. Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the set of all such topologies. Then it turns out that there is a topology $\tau_0\in\mathscr{T}$ such that $\tau_0\subseteq\tau$ for **all** $\tau\in\mathscr{T}$. That is, every topology on $V$ that makes the norm a continuous function has to include all of the open sets in $\tau_0$. This, by the way, is equivalent to saying that $\tau_0=\bigcap\mathscr{T}$. *Weakest topology* here means *coarsest topology*, i.e., the one with the absolute minimum of open sets needed to make the norm function continuous.

Vector addition is a function $+$ from $V\times V$ to $V$. Once we impose the topology $\tau_0$ on $V$, we automatically get a product topology on $V\times V$, and we can ask whether the function $+:V\times V\to V$ is continuous with respect to that product topology on $V\times V$ and the topology $\tau_0$ on $V$. It turns out that it is. In this context *jointly continuous* is just a synonym for *continuous with respect to the product topology*, so (1) is just saying that vector addition is a continuous function. Similarly, the field $K$ has a natural topology $\tau_K$, so $K\times V$ has a product topology defined from $\tau_K$ and $\tau_0$, and (2) is just the claim that the scalar multiplication function

$$\cdot:K\times V\to V:\langle\alpha,v\rangle\mapsto \alpha v$$

is continuous with respect to this product topology in $K\times V$ and the topology $\tau_0$ on $V$.

The reason for the term *jointly continuous* is that it is possible for a function $f:X\times Y\to Z$ that is not continuous nevertheless to be continuous in each variable separately. That is, it’s possible for each function

$$f_x:Y\to Z:y\mapsto f(x,y)$$

with $x\in X$ to be continuous and for each function

$$f^y:X\to Z:x\mapsto f(x,y)$$

with $y\in Y$ to be continuous, without $f:X\times Y\to Z$ being continuous as a function of two variables.

When each function

$$f_x:Y\to Z:y\mapsto f(x,y)$$

with $x\in X$ to be continuous, we say that $f$ is *continuous in the second variable*, and when each function

$$f^y:X\to Z:x\mapsto f(x,y)$$

with $y\in Y$ to be continuous, we say that $f$ is *continuous in the first variable*. If both of these are the case, $f$ is *separately continuous*, but, as I said, this does not guarantee that it is actually continuous as function from the product space $X\times Y$ to the space $Z$.

Comment: Dear Brian M. Scott, you've brilliant teaching skills. You explained everything so well and gave all necessary details. I truly admire and appreciate the spirit of people like you on stack exchange, who never give a second thought before giving helping hand. I thank you with all my gratitude and respect for your time and help.

Comment: @Sara: You’re very welcome, and thank *you*.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a very nice answer, but I thought I could give an example of a function which is discontinuous as a function of two variables, but continuous in each variable. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \\
   \end{cases}
$$

This is discontinuous as it is 1/2 arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ when $x=y$, but it is easily seen to be continuous in each variable.